# Serialier return data isn't changing, but database changes Django Rest Framework

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a problem PATCHing an object in nested serializer.
After I send a PATCH request in Postman the code works fine and database changes occur, but serializer response regarding M2M relations is from previous version of these relations.

Here is the code:

```
class RecipeCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for creating recipe."""

    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(
        many=True
    )
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Tags.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        slug_field='id'
    )
    image = Base64ImageField(required=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = [
            'ingredients',
            'tags',
            'image',
            'name',
            'text',
            'cooking_time',
        ]

    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = RecipeSerializer(value)
        return serializer.data

   
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        new_ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')

        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.text = validated_data.get('text', instance.text)
        instance.cooking_time = validated_data.get(
            'cooking_time',
            instance.cooking_time
        )


        new_ingredients_id_list = [None]
        old_ingredients = RecipeIngredients.objects.filter(
            recipe_id=self.data['id']
        )
        for new in new_ingredients:
            # Updating or creating existing DB objects
            ingredient_id = new.get('id')
            ingredient_amount = new.get('amount')
            # Getting a list of new id's for further use
            new_ingredients_id_list.append(ingredient_id)
            RecipeIngredients.objects.update_or_create(
                ingredient_id=ingredient_id,
                recipe_id=self.data['id'],
                defaults={'amount': ingredient_amount}
            )


        for old in old_ingredients:   
            # deleting removed ingredients from recipe          
            if old.ingredient_id not in new_ingredients_id_list:
                RecipeIngredients.objects.filter(id=old.id).delete()

        instance.save()
        return validated_data
```

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Recipe serializer."""

    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    ingredients = IngredientRecipeSerializer(
        source='recipe_with_ingredient',
        many=True
    )
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    image = Base64ImageField(required=True, allow_null=True)
    is_favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_in_shopping_cart = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = [
            'id',
            'tags',
            'author',
            'ingredients',
            'is_favorited',
            'is_in_shopping_cart',
            'name',
            'image',
            'text',
            'cooking_time'
        ]
```

```
class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Viewset for Recipes."""

    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    queryset = Recipe.objects.prefetch_related(
        'ingredients',
        'tags',
        'author'
    )

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['create', 'update', 'partial_update']:
            return RecipeCreationSerializer
        return self.serializer_class
```

request PATCH data which changes "text" field and removes one of the ingredients:

```
{
    "ingredients": [{
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 69
    },
                    {
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 555
    }],
    "tags": [3, 6],
    "image": "some IMG",
    "name": "Patched_again",
    "text": "txt",
    "cooking_time": 90
}
```

response Data, the changes are correct, but ingredient isn't removed (DATABASE is changed correctly)

```
{
    "id": 47,
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Dinner",
            "color": "#FFFB89",
            "slug": "supper"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Lunch",
            "color": "#2AFF1A",
            "slug": "dinner"
        }
    ],
    "author": {
        "email": "shopcart_tester@gmail.cim",
        "id": 10,
        "username": "shpctre",
        "first_name": "Shop",
        "last_name": "Cart",
        "is_subscribed": false
    },
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "id": 81,
            "name": "Meat",
            "measurement_unit": "kg",
            "amount": 69.0
        },
        {
            "id": 93,
            "name": "Sugar",
            "measurement_unit": "g",
            "amount": 666.0
        },
        {
            "id": 83,
            "name": "Potatoe",
            "measurement_unit": "kg",
            "amount": 555.0
        }
    ],
    "is_favorited": false,
    "is_in_shopping_cart": false,
    "name": "Patched_again",
    "image": "/media/temp.png",
    "text": "txt",
    "cooking_time": 90
```

UPD:
This code helped me with tags

```
        instance.tags.set(new_tags)
        instance.save()
```

but it won't work with ingredients, because I have somehow to pass 'amount' to Ingredient model, which is connecter to Recipe through RecipeIngredient model.